# gesturestart event analog in Chrome for Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

iOS Safari has `GestureEvent` objects, that are sent on `gesturestart, gesturechange` and `gestureend` multitouch events.

Is there any analog of this in Chrome for Android?

When a user touches the screen with two fingers, and then does a pinching gesture without lifting the fingers from the screen, the usual `touchstart/move/end` events are not dispatched, while `gesturestart, gesturechange` and `gestureend` multitouch events do not seem to exist in Chrome for Android.

How can this multi-finger gesture be detected in Chrome for Android?

Answer (score 4):

Gestures cannot be detected directly in Chrome for Android.  We just don't have it implemented, and I believe we are unlikely to implement it.

Mutliple touchstarts should be happening fine in Android.  If not then I suspect you don't have your viewport locked to device-width;

I have created a simple test http://jsbin.com/ipibup/latest which locks the viewport and it works (however if you scroll it appears there is a bug as touch end will not trigger).

Comment: "We just don't have it implemented, and I believe we are unlikely to implement it." I'm a bit unhappy to read that. Why?

Comment: I believe it is a IP issue with Apple.

Comment: So just rename it? ;)